vue2 project memory usage is high causing browser crash, how to troubleshoot and save me
enter image description here
Clear timers, destroy components, etc
Partial code:
    <div id="member" v-if="isMemberShow" v-observe-visibility="onVisibilityMember">
        <div class="sh-card-header">会员资料</div>
        <MEMBER ref="member" v-if="visibilityMember" :clientId='$store.state.communicate.userInfoDrawer.tempInfo.clientId'></MEMBER>
    </div>

    onVisibilityMember(isVisible, entry){
        // 防止滚动加载多次，记录一下一次加载
        let num = 0
        if(num == 0 && isVisible){
          num = 1
          this.visibilityMember = isVisible
        }
    }

